# Building an object dynamically in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, dom-events

I have an object defined as:

```
outobject = [];
```

And after building the object with the data, this object has ten items of four columns as follows:

```
id: 1
name : "abc"
date: "11/1/2012"
type : "normal"

id : 2
name : "def"
date : "11/2/2012"
type : "normal"
```

and so on.

Now I am looping through the objects and doing a calculation and ultimately I would like to add one more column in the object like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < outobject.length; i++) {

//do some calculation, I got output as "Brazil" for this particular instance of outobject[i]

outobject[i].push({
                        locationname: "Brazil"
                    });

}
```

I am getting an exception during at this point :

```
outobject[i].push({
                        locationname: "Brazil"
                    });
```

Is it possible to add data like this, I am doing this "location" because it has to be calculated on the fly

Comment: Should be like this: `outobject[i].locationname = "brazil";` Push is used to add items to an array. `outobject[i]` is not an array, it's an object.

Comment: `outobject = [];` — That's an array

Comment: "And after building the object with the data" — Which you are doing … how?

Comment: "Now I am looping through the objects" — When did the object become plural?

Comment: "I am getting an exception" — What exception are you getting?

Comment: I'm glad the answer below helped. It's still useful to edit the question with the relevant details requested above, for the benefit of future readers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to assume that when you say you've filled in the object (which is an array), you've done something like this:

```
outobject[0] = {
    id: 1,
    name : "abc",
    date: "11/1/2012",
    type : "normal"
};
```

or

```
outobject.push({
    id: 1,
    name : "abc",
    date: "11/1/2012",
    type : "normal"
});
```

...and so on for the other three entries.

This:

```
outobject[i].push({
    locationname: "Brazil"
})
```

...tries to treat the object at entry `i` as though it were an array, but there's nothing in your question suggesting that it's an array.

If your goal is to add a  *fifth* item:

```
outobject.push({
    locationname: "Brazil"
});
```

If your goal is to *add* a `locationname` property to the object at `outobject[i]`, then:

```
outobject[i].locationname = "Brazil";
```